# Ok to use solid furnace wire to connect this 24v transformer to my nest?

Tags: electrical

I just want to make sure I wired this up correctly using the correct wire. It works!

https://www.elkproducts.com/product-catalog/elk-trg1640-ac-transformer-16-5-vac-45-va-auto-resetting-grounding-prong-and-terminal

[image]

Comment: I think the nest needs to be powered by the same transformer as your HVAC system.  The nest will power on the way you have it wired, but might not properly control things so double check the manual or be on the lookout for issues.

Comment: Adam, I looked at your other question, and I wouldn't hook up the thermostat this way.  See [my answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/186958/43874) over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that size is enough. Solid wire is harder to bend then stranded but this isn't an issue unless you move or use the wire often.